# Turn off heated bed in Repetier?

Tags: heated-bed, software, repetier

I have a printrbot simple metal with the heated bed upgrade. I think theirs a problem with my board, so long story short, I'm just trying to print without actually heating up the bed. The problem I am faced with is when I try to print from Repetier, it's still trying to connect the heated bed. I can't find any settings for shutting this off anywhere. How can I bypass this so I can still print? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to post-process your gcode files manually removing all `M140` and `M190` instructions (the one setting heated bed temperatures).

You can do that manually by opening your GCODE file in a text editor and searching for `M140` and `M190`, but I recently had the same problem with Slic3r (Prusa edition) and I wrote a [one-liner](https://github.com/prusa3d/Slic3r/issues/638#issuecomment-352229698) that does that automatically for me.

Answer (score 0):

I set Slicer->Configuration->Filament->Bed Temperature to 0 and this also removes the G-Code line mentioned in mac's Answer.

I think this bug is particularly annoying because the printer (at least my Velleman Vertex) is stuck in the "Heating Bed"-State and I had to do a power cycle.